# JourneyBuilder issues - beacon library excluded

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, android

I'm excluding the beacon library while declaring gradle dependency since I do not need it, for simple implementation of push notifications. Although I'm getting following error during compilation.

Warning:com.salesforce.marketingcloud.MCProximityService: can't find superclass or interface org.altbeacon.beacon.BeaconConsumer and many others in MCProximityService
Warning:com.salesforce.marketingcloud.proximity.BeaconLogger: can't find referenced class org.altbeacon.beacon.logging.Logger.
Warning:com.salesforce.marketingcloud.proximity.b: can't find referenced class org.altbeacon.beacon.service.BeaconService

http://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/JB4A-SDK-Android/

Are MCProximityService class and other beacon library dependents placed in the correct module? Am I missing something?

I am getting this error while running Proguard. I may need to safeguard some classes, although from the package name they look like they are/should be part of beacon library.

```
Warning:com.salesforce.marketingcloud.MCProximityService: can't find superclass or interface org.altbeacon.beacon.BeaconConsumer
Warning:com.salesforce.marketingcloud.MCProximityService: can't find superclass or interface org.altbeacon.beacon.MonitorNotifier
Warning:com.salesforce.marketingcloud.proximity.BeaconLogger: can't find superclass or interface org.altbeacon.beacon.logging.Logger
Warning:com.salesforce.marketingcloud.MCProximityService: can't find referenced class org.altbeacon.beacon.BeaconConsumer
Warning:com.salesforce.marketingcloud.MCProximityService: can't find referenced class org.altbeacon.beacon.BeaconManager
Warning:com.salesforce.marketingcloud.MCProximityService: can't find referenced class org.altbeacon.beacon.BeaconParser
Warning:com.salesforce.marketingcloud.MCProximityService: can't find referenced class org.altbeacon.beacon.Identifier
Warning:com.salesforce.marketingcloud.MCProximityService: can't find referenced class org.altbeacon.beacon.MonitorNotifier
Warning:com.salesforce.marketingcloud.MCProximityService: can't find referenced class org.altbeacon.beacon.Region
Warning:com.salesforce.marketingcloud.MCProximityService: can't find referenced class org.altbeacon.beacon.powersave.BackgroundPowerSaver
Warning:com.salesforce.marketingcloud.MCProximityService: can't find referenced class org.altbeacon.beacon.BeaconManager
Warning:com.salesforce.marketingcloud.MCProximityService: can't find referenced class org.altbeacon.beacon.BeaconParser
Warning:com.salesforce.marketingcloud.MCProximityService: can't find referenced class org.altbeacon.beacon.Identifier
Warning:com.salesforce.marketingcloud.MCProximityService: can't find referenced class org.altbeacon.beacon.Region
Warning:com.salesforce.marketingcloud.MCProximityService: can't find referenced class org.altbeacon.beacon.powersave.BackgroundPowerSaver
Warning:com.salesforce.marketingcloud.MCProximityService: can't find referenced class org.altbeacon.beacon.BeaconManager
Warning:com.salesforce.marketingcloud.MCProximityService: can't find referenced class org.altbeacon.beacon.powersave.BackgroundPowerSaver
Warning:com.salesforce.marketingcloud.MCProximityService: can't find referenced class org.altbeacon.beacon.Region
Warning:com.salesforce.marketingcloud.proximity.BeaconLogger: can't find referenced class org.altbeacon.beacon.logging.Logger
Warning:com.salesforce.marketingcloud.proximity.b: can't find referenced class org.altbeacon.beacon.service.BeaconService
Warning:there were 35 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
```

Comment: Please provide the actual stacktrace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please add the following line to your `proguard.cfg` file if you're using v5.0.x of the SDK:

```
-dontwarn org.altbeacon.**                     // if you excluded the AltBeacon Library
-dontwarn com.google.android.gms.location.**   // if you excluded the Google Play Services Location component
```

I will open a bug ticket to address this in our next release.